# How to change default behaviour of TTL in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

When I used TTL to make data expired in mongodb, I was wondering if there is a way to modify the default behavior of TTL, which currently will remove the expired data.

For example, I have data with the fields `isUsed` and `expiredAt`, when data expires, I want to reset `isUsed` to `false` instead of removing it. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: @Salvador Dali is correct. The docs should explain how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not change this. [TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-ttl) stands for "time to live", not time to modify, or time to trigger a custom function.

> Stands for “time to live” and represents an expiration time or period
>   for a given piece of information to remain in a cache or other
>   temporary storage before the system deletes it or ages it out.

So if you really need to do something like this, you have to write your custom logic.